# Toggle sound off straight away

Tags: swift, swiftui, avaudioplayer, audio-player, togglebutton

I have created a toggle button to turn off/on the music. This problem is i have to close the application for it to take effect.

This is what i use to begin the music:

```
.onAppear(perform: {self.musicM.playSoundBand(sound: "Band", type: "wav")})
```

Here is my toggle button:

```
 Toggle(isOn: self.$musicM.mOn) {
                    ZStack {
                        Image("Button")
                            .renderingMode(.original)
                            .resizable()
                            .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 180))
                            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 40);
                        Text("Music")
                            .padding(.all, 20)
                            .padding([.leading, .trailing], 40)
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .foregroundColor(.black)
                    }
                    Spacer()
                }.onTapGesture(perform: {if self.musicM.mOn == false { self.musicM.pauseMusicBand(); self.soundEffectsM.playSound(sound: "GunCock", type: "wav")}})
```

I have tried variations and utilising .stop() but still wont work. If it helps here is my soundmanager class also:

```
class musicModel: ObservableObject {
    var audioPlayerBand:AVAudioPlayer?
    @Published var mOn: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "mOn") {
        didSet {
            UserDefaults.standard.set(self.mOn, forKey: "mOn")
        }
    }
    func pauseMusicBand() {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "mOn"); audioPlayerBand?.pause()
    }
    func setVolume(volume: Float) {
        audioPlayerBand?.volume = volume
    }
    func playSoundBand(sound: String, type: String) {
        if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: sound, ofType: type) {
            do {
                audioPlayerBand = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
                audioPlayerBand?.numberOfLoops =  -1
                audioPlayerBand?.play()
            } catch {
                print("ERROR: Could not find sound file!")
            }; if self.mOn == false { pauseMusicBand() }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what the problem is from reading; 
"This problem is i have to close the application for it to take effect." and 
"I have tried variations and utilising .stop() but still wont work."

Please explain the problem in a different way.

Comment: Ok i will try to be clearer. In my app i have background music playing. I have created a toggle button which will allow the users to mute the music if they like. The problem is it doesn't mute it straight away, the music continues to play until i close the application and when i open it again the music will then be muted. I hope i have explained it in a better manner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This test code shows how you can toggle your sound off straight away:

```
import SwiftUI
import Foundation
import AVFoundation

struct ContentView: View {

@ObservedObject var musicM = musicModel()

var body: some View {
        Toggle(isOn: Binding<Bool>(
            get: { self.musicM.mOn },
            set: { self.musicM.mOn = $0; self.doMusic() })) {
            ZStack {
                Image("Button")
                    .renderingMode(.original)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: 180))
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 40);
                Text("Music")
                    .padding(.all, 20)
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing], 40)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
            }
            Spacer()
    }.onAppear(perform: self.startBackgroundMusic)
}

func startBackgroundMusic() {
    // if you want to always start the background music, then toggle should be set
//        self.musicM.mOn = true
//        self.musicM.playSoundBand(sound: "Band", type: "wav")

    // if you want to play the background music only if the user has set it last time
    if self.musicM.mOn {
        self.musicM.playSoundBand(sound: "Band", type: "wav")
    }
}

func doMusic() {
    if self.musicM.mOn {
        self.musicM.playSoundBand(sound: "Band", type: "wav")
    } else {
        self.musicM.audioPlayerBand?.pause()
     //   self.soundEffectsM.playSound(sound: "GunCock", type: "wav")
    }
}
}

class musicModel: ObservableObject {
var audioPlayerBand: AVAudioPlayer?

@Published var mOn: Bool = UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "mOn") {
    didSet {
        UserDefaults.standard.set(self.mOn, forKey: "mOn")
    }
}
func pauseMusicBand() {
    UserDefaults.standard.set(false, forKey: "mOn")
    audioPlayerBand?.pause()
}
func setVolume(volume: Float) {
    audioPlayerBand?.volume = volume
}
func playSoundBand(sound: String, type: String) {
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: sound, ofType: type) {
        do {
            audioPlayerBand = try AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path))
            audioPlayerBand?.numberOfLoops =  -1
            audioPlayerBand?.play()
        } catch {
            print("ERROR: Could not find sound file!")
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much but it didn't work. The music still continues to play until the app is closed then opened again. It might be me because im not sure where to call the 'doMusic' function. i tried to call it instead of 'self.startBackgroundMusic' but there was no change.

Comment: The code as shown works without any problems. Can you post the code that you use?

Comment: Nope it was just me being an idiot and calling the functions incorrectly. You're code works like a dream thank you so much!